# ffmpeg not using all cores

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, multi-core

I just got a new server with two Intel E5-2695 processors but was shocked to see that FFmpeg or Ubuntu doesn't utilize all the cores.

Here's the output from `top` while FFmpeg was running:

```
top - 23:35:25 up  2:41,  2 users,  load average: 5.35, 4.37, 3.12
Tasks: 333 total,   2 running, 331 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu0  :  0.0 us,  1.0 sy, 35.6 ni, 63.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu1  :  0.0 us,  0.7 sy, 35.5 ni, 63.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  :  0.0 us,  0.7 sy, 33.4 ni, 65.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu3  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy, 32.7 ni, 67.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu4  :  0.0 us,  0.3 sy, 32.3 ni, 67.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu5  :  0.0 us,  0.3 sy, 33.0 ni, 66.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu6  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy, 32.6 ni, 67.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu7  :  0.0 us,  0.3 sy, 32.7 ni, 67.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu8  :  0.0 us,  0.7 sy, 32.6 ni, 66.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu9  :  0.0 us,  0.3 sy, 33.9 ni, 65.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu10 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy, 35.0 ni, 65.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu11 :  0.0 us,  0.7 sy, 30.0 ni, 69.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu12 : 21.1 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 78.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu13 :  0.7 us,  0.0 sy,  4.3 ni, 95.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu14 :  0.3 us,  0.0 sy,  5.0 ni, 94.6 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu15 : 24.9 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 75.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu16 :  0.3 us,  0.0 sy,  3.7 ni, 96.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu17 :  0.7 us,  0.3 sy,  4.9 ni, 94.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu18 :  1.0 us,  0.0 sy,  4.6 ni, 94.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu19 :  0.7 us,  0.0 sy,  4.7 ni, 94.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu20 : 11.1 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 88.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu21 :  1.3 us,  0.0 sy,  4.6 ni, 94.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu22 :  2.0 us,  0.3 sy,  4.3 ni, 93.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu23 : 96.7 us,  1.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  2.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu24 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.7 ni, 99.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu25 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  3.0 ni, 97.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu26 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  1.3 ni, 98.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu27 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  4.0 ni, 96.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu28 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  1.7 ni, 98.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu29 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  1.7 ni, 98.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu30 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  1.7 ni, 98.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu31 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  1.0 ni, 99.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu32 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.7 ni, 99.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu33 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  1.7 ni, 98.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu34 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  2.0 ni, 98.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu35 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  1.0 ni, 99.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu36 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
```

Here's what I've tried:

- Sending FFmpeg with `-threads 0`
- Sending FFmpeg with `-threads 500`
- Compiled FFmpeg with `--enable-pthreads`
- Setting `-sws_flags fast_bilinear`
- Run with `nice -20`

You can see from this sceenshot that only the first thread is fully utilized and only the first few threads are in `running state`, the rest are in `sleep state`:

[image]

Here's the command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i hdvd.mkv -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -threads 0 
  -s 1836x1080 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -vf -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental -movflags faststart hdvd_1080p.mp4 
  -s 1224x720 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -vf -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental -movflags faststart hdvd_720p.mp4 
  -s 816x480 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -vf -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental -movflags faststart hdvd_480p.mp4 
  -s 612x360 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -vf -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental -movflags faststart hdvd_360p.mp4 
  -s 408x240 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -vf -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental -movflags faststart hdvd_240p.mp4 
  -s 244x144 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental -movflags faststart hdvd_144p.mp4
```

FFmpeg info:

```
ffmpeg version N-57989-g76a47d6 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov  9 2013 14:28:54 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfaac --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libspeex --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --enable-pthreads
```

Comment: Please do not crosspost the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19758549/1109017) on several [se] sites.

Comment: Can you please post the complete ffmpeg command you are using.

Comment: And ask a question. Otherwise I could guess if the question is if you were really shocked or just a little bit shocked about it.

Comment: @szatmary edited.

Comment: Interesting, that is a 12 core CPU, which you have 2 of.  Thats 24 cores, plus hyperthreading.  You should see 48 cores...

Comment: @Keltari you see it in htop screenshot. my screen is not big enoght to include `top` output.

Answer (score 5):

x264 is very heavily threaded. It should be able to use 100% of the CPU if you can feed frames to it fast enough. So something else is bottle-necking. In your case it is most likely the scaler. Scaling is actually a very difficult problem, and is single threaded in ffmpeg. To test this theory, you can try a fast scaler like `-sws_flags fast_bilinear`. Running a separate command per output may help as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully competent about how ffmpeg internally works but it is very normal that you see half of the cores are waiting idle. CPU utilization is something different from Core utilization. One process can only use one CPU so this is the main problem. You can further read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4759192/3733068) to get the idea behind multi-cpu programming.

Also as @szatmary replied you should be sure about ffmpeg is feeded by enough frames per second.